# Why does stored procedure return datetime but query returns date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that returns, among other things, a date field (Note: I recently changed this from a datetime field). When I run the stored procedure it is still returning the field as datetime. Even if I make a new stored procedure it still returns datetime and not date. Why? A simple query just returns the date (which is what I want). To make things stranger, running the sp in SSMS gives me the results I want. However, running the sp from the visual studio connection gives me the extra time (as seen several steps below).

sp:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.get_steps_detail
@proj_id int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SELECT        step_date, step_stat
    FROM            steps_table 
    WHERE proj_id = @proj_id ORDER BY step_num 
END
```

returns like this

```
Running [dbo].[get_steps_detail] ( @proj_id = 1 ).

step_date                      step_stat                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
------------------------------ --------------------------------------------------------- 
2014-02-06 00:00:00.0000000    1     
2014-01-30 00:00:00.0000000    1     
2014-01-30 00:00:00.0000000    1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
2014-01-30 00:00:00.0000000    1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
No rows affected.
(4 row(s) returned)
@RETURN_VALUE = 0
Finished running [dbo].[get_steps_detail].
```

Whereas if I run a simple query:

```
SELECT        step_date, step_stat
FROM            steps_table
WHERE        (proj_id = 1)
ORDER BY step_num
```

I get simply the date

```
2/6/2014    1
1/30/2014   1
1/30/2014   1
1/30/2014   1
```

The 'step_date' column is clearly defined as 'Date' (and not datetime) type. What am I missing here? I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 Express. I also tried stopping and starting the server but that didn`t seem to help anything. Do I need to do anything to 'refresh' the stored proc? In fact, even if I change it to this

```
SELECT CAST(step_date AS DATE) ...
```

I STILL get the extra time added on both in the visual studio results set and in my web app (turned caching off for this btw). Is this some SQL bug?

Comment: What client tool are you running these in? It doesn't look like SQL Server Management Studio. Run both of these in SQL Server Management Studio - what do you see?

Comment: TO make it even simpler, run these in SQL Server Management Studio: `SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS DATETIME)` `SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)`

Comment: here the same thing i have did with same example date time nothing differentiates

Comment: Interesting...you`re right. SSMS gives me the results I would expect (no time, just date). I was just running it from the visual studio db connection. The problem is that the stored procedure is returning the date+time in my web app as well. Will check out the cast shortly

Comment: Arg. Even if I do this SELECT CAST (step_date AS DATE) I still get date + time back in my web app!

Comment: @user3302828 Can be Visual Studio uses .NET for it and then basically puts the value into a DateTIme struct - because there is no pure date in .NET. Then the output - does not use metadata to change the format string and boom - there is a time.

Comment: @TomTom. Could be, but that seems odd that something so simple would require workarounds for every web app (perhaps not surprising though). I am going to end up having to select each datepart individually for now and then combine them in my code behind

Comment: @user3302828 It acutally totally DOES Require a workaround for every web app because .NET has no Date and no DateTime data type. Any value you pull IS ALWAYS A DATETIME - and there is no metadata whether one part is missing. So, every .NET app has to filter that itself by definition. I think that is an omission (date and time data types) but things are how they are.

Comment: @TomTom: Then how do you explain the time-part being stripped in .NET when performing the SELECT query directly instead of calling the Stored Proc? In any case, this is a .NET issue, that has nothing to do with SQL server.

Comment: @Dan likels a metadata lookup that results in a customzed overload in visualization - and this one missing in a SP.

Comment: @TomTom Ok, thanks. I agree, it is definitely an omission. That`s ok though, the workaround is pretty easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Total workaround here but I ended up doing this for now:

```
SELECT DATEPART(year, step_date) AS step_date_year, DATEPART(month, step_date) AS step_date_month, DATEPART(day, step_date) AS step_date_day
```

and then combining the three in their control like this

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ><%# Eval("step_date_year")%> - <%# Eval("step_date_month")%> - <%# Eval("step_date_day")%></asp:Label>
```

Seems really clunky to have to do this workaround for something so simple, although on the plus side I can now choose whether to use '/', ':' or '-' in between month date and year